# Data Extension Caching - Ampscript personalisation storing test email addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, send-email

Using AMPscript in one on my email campaigns, I'm pulling data together (from a DE) based on if a family/ single person share the same Policy Number. I then pull their SubscriberKey (ID), Relationship (Type), First and Last Name into a table within the email. A bit like the below table.

```
Type            Last Name, First Name      ID
Primary Insured Fruit, Watermelon          2163913
Spouse          Fruit, Papaya              2163914
Child           Fruit, Durian              2163917
Child           Fruit, Longan              2163915
Child           Fruit, Lychee              2163916
```

AMPscript is as followed...

```
 %%[ 
set @PolicyNumber = AttributeValue("Policy_Number")
IF NOT EMPTY(@PolicyNumber) THEN
set @rows = LookupRows("Policy_data","Policy_Number",@PolicyNumber)
set @rc = RowCount(@rows)

for @i = 1 TO @rc DO
set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
set @fName = Field(@row, "first_name")
set @relationship = Field(@row, "relationship")
set @subscriberkey = Field(@row, "SubscriberKey")
set @lName = Field(@row, "Last_Name")
]%%
<tr>
  <td>%%=v(@relationship)=%%</td>
  <td>%%=v(@lName)=%%, %%=v(@fName)=%%</td>
  <td>%%=v(@subscriberkey)=%%</td>
</tr>
%%[next @i
endif]%%
```

Table I used.

```
Policy_Number|Last_Name|First_Name|SubscriberKey|Relationship|EmailAddress
1|Fruit|Watermelon|2163913|Primary Insured|123@gmail.com
1|Fruit|Papaya|2163914|Spouse|
1|Fruit|Durian|2163917|Child|
1|Fruit|Longan|2163915|Child|
1|Fruit|Lychee|2163916|Child|
2|Pie|Apple|90251091|Primary Insured|123abc@gmail.com
2|Pie|Cherry|90251092|Spouse|
3|Baker|Yummy|90257611|Primary Insured|cba@gmail.com
3|Baker|Junior|90257700|Child|
4|Ice Cream|Chocolate|90251111|Primary Insured|xxxx@hotmail.com
```

The code work and I tested it out on several bits of data with 4 email addresses. All worked and pull the correct data. I then changed those four email addresses to colleagues of mine to show them. But I still received the emails and they didn't. I was wondering if there could be any caching going on? And if so, how to clear it with the DE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email addresses are stored in All Subscribers list, you need to change them there.

Go to Email Studio > Subscribers > Lists > All Subscribers and Search by Subscriber Key and update emails in All Subscribers - emails in Data Extension only matter for the first send.

> In Salesforce Marketing Cloud, the All Subscribers list is a master
> list of all people, or Subscribers, who can receive email
> communications from your organization. When an email is sent from the
> platform and the Subscriber does not exist in the All Subscribers
> list, they are appended to it as a new record. Now, Subscriber email
> addresses can change. In most scenarios, the platform applies email
> address changes to the Subscriber record at send time, but in certain
> scenarios, you may need to update Subscribers email addresses in the
> All Subscribers list before sending an email, to ensure that it’s sent
> to the correct email address.

Source and video: https://mc.chat/subscriber-email-address-update-behavior/

Comment: Ah, of course! Appreciate the quick response! Thank you!